# Remove shadow from action bar - kotlin

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, layout, android-actionbar

I'm currently working on an app with a very light design and I don't know how to remove this visible lines / transitions between the action bar an the app content aswell as the transition between content and bottom navigation drawer. Both elements have the same color. The java code for that is

`getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);` but what is the kotlin code?

You can see the lines in the screenshot.

[image]

It would be really nice if someone could help me with this problem.

Comment: add xml code of this screen. so can guide much easily

Comment: Ok I'm sorry for that. But I found out that i can remove the shadow below the action bar with `getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);` but I don't know the kotlin code for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This similar code would work:

```
getSupportActionBar()?.setElevation(0f)
```

but AS would propose property access syntax which is used in Kotlin:

```
supportActionBar?.elevation = 0f
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
Do you also know how to remove the shadow of the bottom navigation drawer?

Comment: Set this attribute: `app:elevation="0dp"`

Comment: In Kotlin: `bottomNavigationView.elevation = 0f` but it requires API 21+